# Foreach loop syntax error

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
private V[] elements;

public int size(){
  int returnValue = 0;
  for(TableEntry<K,V> pointer :  elements){
    while(pointer != null){
      returnValue++;
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

And I get error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type V to SimpleHashtable.TableEntry in foreach line.

Here is complete class: [Code](http://hastebin.com/mazuquruva.coffee)

Comment: elements is an array of `V`, not an array of  `TableEntry<K, V>`...

Comment: Is TableEntry some subclass of Hash table?

Comment: Your problem is not about the for loop, but about how you mix and cast between V and TableEntry in your code. You need to choose one or the other...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get `TableEntry` objects from an array of `V` (`elements`). This will not work.

Also, your loop is double, for each entry in the array you try to search through the rest of the array.

Try this instead:

```
public int size() {
    int returnValue = 0;
    for (V pointer : elements)
        if (pointer != null) {
            returnValue++;
        }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of pointer variable to `V`.

```
for (V pointer : elements) {
    \\ loop body
}
```

Comment: `V` doesn't have to implement `Iterable`, he is iterating over an array not over `V`. See [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).